# Is SharedPreferences' defaultValue always read as String when defined in .xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to retrieve a default value:

Definition:

```
<integer name="keyOfDefaultValue">2</integer>
```

Referenced as:

```
android:defaultValue="@integer/keyOfDefaultValue"
```

Actual code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
int intVar = sharedPrefs.getInt(keyOfDefaultValue, fallbackIntValue);
```

I get `ClassCastException`s stating that I'm trying to cast String to an Integer. I've read the Android docs about default values:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android:defaultValue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android%3adefaultValue)

so I expected to work with the correct type, but apparently I get a String.

Can someone confirm that default values defined in .xml are always to be retrieved as Strings? Or you could just point me to a page in the documentation where this is explained...

Thanks

Comment: `fallbackIntValue` is a string or integer?

Comment: @Rani, it's an integer but this wasn't relevant so I omitted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you check the return value on AOSP code for different types of preference

`EditTextPreference`, `ListPreference` return String values

`SwitchPreference`,`CheckBoxPreference`  returns boolean

`MultiSelectListPreference` returns a set of strings

If you want to change it, I guess you can always override
onGetDefaultValue in your customPreference , if you have one

Comment: Thanks! I haven't looked at the `getValue()` method but now I see how it works.